# How to summarize statistics by two or more factor variables using group_by?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, aggregate

I have a data-frame like this

```
no        date          charges
050034    2011-07-14    3312.00
000859    2012-07-13    10913.54
05266     2013-07-16    159.00
000859    2012-07-13    370.00 
000859    2014-07-16    21881.36
38027     2012-07-13    164.00
```

I want to find average total charges group by each no and date in unique date.
I used

```
summary<-df %>% group_by(no) %>% summarize_each(funs(total_charges=sum(charges)))
```

to get result like this:

```
no        date          charges
050034    2011-07-14    3312.00
000859    2012-07-13    11283.54
05266     2013-07-16    159.00
000859    2014-07-16    21881.36
38027     2012-07-13    164.00
```

(we only have one no=000859 at 2012-07-13)
but my code does not work correctly!

EDIT::::::
How could I find average of total charges per month for each no?

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus I did not find any similar question before posting my question!

Comment: no problem, hope your problem is solved now

Comment: I edited my question to be more specified

Comment: The question should stay closer imo as it is explained in the duplicate-target. You have to use both `no` and `month` as grouping variables. You can create the `month` variable with for example `lubridate::month(date)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data frame is called `df` you can use:

```
aggregate(charges ~ no + date, data=df, sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group by more than one variable:

`df%>%group_by(date,no)%>%summarise(total_charges=sum(charges))`

Comment: how could I find total charges average per no in each month?

Comment: @Sajjad your question asked for total, so this answer used `sum`. The R function for calculating averages is `mean()`, so if you want the average instead of the total  you should use `mean()` instead of `sum()`. You may look at some of the introductory resources [in the R tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info).